# Problems with variables with spaces

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote a small script that copies, then removes and then creates a symbolic link from where the file was moved to it's new location.
To easly do it for multiple times I used variables, but when a file has spaces in it, I'm getting some errors, even though I'm using '\' in front of every space.
Here is my code:

```
dest=~/Videos-win/file\ name\ with\ spaces
src=~/Downloads/file\ name\ with\ spaces

echo $dest ;
cp -r $src $dest ;
rm -R $src ;
ln -s $dest $src ;
echo 'done'
```

I also tried with '\\' (adding '\ ' to the var). also got me some errors.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
dest="$HOME/Videos-win/file name with spaces"
src="$HOME/Downloads/file name with spaces"

echo "$dest"
cp -r "$src" "$dest"
rm -R "$src"
ln -s "$dest" "$src"
echo 'done'
```

Please, USE MORE QUOTES! They are vital. Also, learn the difference between `'` and `"` and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Answer (score 1):

Your variables will have the "spaced" values, but then the spaces will be passed through to the the `cp` `rm` and `ln` commands.

Put double quotes around the variables where you actually use them to ensure the whole value (including spaces) is passed to the command as a single argument.

try:

```
cp -r "$src" "$dest"
rm -R "$src"
ln -s "$dest" "$src"
```

... and you don't need all the semicolons...

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes:

```
cp -r "$src" "$dest" ;
```

...